# Routes not rendering views when Component refactored into its own file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a NavBar component in my App class. When I put the contents of the NavBar component directly into the App, everything works as it should (the Links call the Routes and the different pages are rendered). However, when I import the NavBar component into the App class the NavBar shows up, but clicking the Links do not change the views. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

App.js with NavBar contents directly placed in

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import Home from "./components/home/Home";
import ShowProfile from "./components/profile/ShowProfile";
import ChatRoom from "./components/chatroom/ChatRoom";
import CreateProfile from "./components/profile/CreateProfile";
import LoginPage from "./components/auth/LoginPage";
//import NavBar from "./components/navbar/NavBar";

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
          <Nav className="flex-column SideNav">
            <Nav.Item>
              <NavLink activeClassName='activeLogo' className='nav-link logo' to='/home' style={ {padding: '30px 0px 20px 40px'}}>Logo</NavLink>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <NavLink activeClassName='active' className='nav-link' to='/profile'>My Profile</NavLink>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/chatroom'>My ChatRoom</NavLink>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
          <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/profile' exact component={ShowProfile}/>
          <Route path='/chatroom' component={ChatRoom}/>
          <Route path='/profile/create' component={CreateProfile}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.js with NavBar imported

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import Home from "./components/home/Home";
import ShowProfile from "./components/profile/ShowProfile";
import ChatRoom from "./components/chatroom/ChatRoom";
import CreateProfile from "./components/profile/CreateProfile";
import LoginPage from "./components/auth/LoginPage";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar/NavBar";

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
          <NavBar/>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
          <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/profile' exact component={ShowProfile}/>
          <Route path='/chatroom' component={ChatRoom}/>
          <Route path='/profile/create' component={CreateProfile}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Edit: NavBar Component**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
    import './NavBar.css';
    import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

    class NavBar extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
      <Nav className="flex-column SideNav">
        <Nav.Item>
          <NavLink activeClassName='activeLogo' className='nav-link logo' to='/home' style={ {padding: '30px 0px 20px 40px'}}>Logo</NavLink>
        </Nav.Item>

        <Nav.Item>
          <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
        </Nav.Item>

        <Nav.Item>
          <NavLink activeClassName='active' className='nav-link' to='/profile'>My Profile</NavLink>
        </Nav.Item>

        <Nav.Item>
          <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/chatroom'>My ChatRoom</NavLink>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: any error on your console?

Comment: @AngelSalazar no but in my NavBar component file if I remove Router and Route from imports the NavBar doesn't render the Links even though it says they are not being used

Comment: can you show your Navbar component?

Comment: @AngelSalazar yes

Comment: Your code is looks good to me. It's working fine at my end. May be a cache issue. Try to clear the cache. Another suggestion is don't add `bootstrap.css` at every page, instead add in `index.js` file.

Comment: You should delete unused import. Also make use of  `<Switch>` in Router.

Comment: @ravibagul91 there was a chrome update. I updated and cleared the cache, restarted the server, and added the switch. Removing the non used imports completely messed up the rendering of the NavBar. My links don't even work. Really  strange.

Comment: Really strange. Same code working at my end. Can you tell me the version of chrome? Also can you try the same with other browser?

Comment: @ravibagul91 chrome 76 on windows 10. Would it be helpful if I linked the github repository of the entire app? Maybe there's something I'm doing in index.js or somewhere else

Comment: @ravibagul91 actually just fixed it. Instead of import {BrowserRouter as NavLink} I just imported {NavLink}. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the import statement in NavBar.js from `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";` to `import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";` fixed the issue. This is because BrowserRouter only applies to Router, Route, and Switch.